# how to use jquery selectors in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to acheive this :

```
for (i = <?php echo $current_i ?> /*then I get augmented in javascript */;i<max;i++){
$('#anyid****')./* my actions goes here */
}
```

here i want to put the counter I of the javascript in the selector 
how could i do that ???

Comment: you must be kidding? in php you concatenate with . in javascript with a +

Comment: thx downvoters
but i think my question is clear and i found an answer

Comment: Generally you *don't* want to run selectors in a loop. Do a single selection of all the DOM elements, then perform the `/* my actions go here */` part on the set. There are plenty of selectors to accommodate complex selection like what you're attempting.

Comment: in my situation i can't use the selectors you are talking about cuz 
i have some divs with ID's and they affect some inputs with OtherId'S 
and my problem is the inputs and the divs are augmented by a script (click to add another) then i can't use $(this) or any $(div)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry i don't know PHP but i hope you wanted to do something like below

```
for (i = <?php echo $current_i ?> ;i<max;i++){
$('#div'+i)/*do the rest*/
}
```

the + is for concatenation, i hope it is same in PHP. Also you could cast i to string.

#### Just for OP's understanding

in line 2 `$('#div'+i)` `i` is a integer type and others `$(#div)` are of type string. For jquery needs a string selector to retrieve a matching dom node and for that `i` needs to also be casted/converted to a string variable so that it could concatenate/add/attach with the prefix string which is in this example `#div`. in c# you add 2 strings like this `var result = "#div" + i.ToString();` and i did not know PHP equivalent for `+` in c#,hence a sorry at the start of post. Now do you understand?

Comment: i am not sure about what you mean but yes 
 i want a selector in jquery to select increasingly Id's

Comment: yes i understand nad the php equivalant is 
`<?php echo "div".(string)$i; ?>`

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = <?php echo $current_i ?> /*then I get augmented in javascript */;i<max;i++){
    $('#anyid' + i)./* my actions goes here */
}
```

you can just concatenate it to the string of your selector.

Answer (score 1):

That's not very "jQuery-ish". Assuming the elements have IDs with a continuing part and are in order, you can give every element a common class and use [`slice` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) and [`each` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('.commonClass').slice(<?php echo $current_i ?>, max + 1).each(...
```

You could provide better solutions if you explain more about your problem. E.g. giving each element an increasing ID does not seem to be a deliberate solution.

*P.S.: I wouldn't put the PHP variable there either, maybe assign the value to a JavaScript variable first.*

Answer (score 1):

it would be a lot cleaner if you split up the php and javascript like this.

js_var.php

```
<?php
    $phpvars = array(
        'max' => 12,
        'fop' => 22
    );

    function phpvar($key = NULL){ 
        global $phpvars;
        return ($key) 
            ? json_encode($phpvars[$key])
            : json_encode($phpvars);
    }
?>
```

usage

```
<?php include('phpvars.php');?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.phpvars = <?=phpvar()?>;

    var max = phpvars.max;

    for (var i=0;i<max;i++){
        console.log(i);
    }
    console.log(php);
</script>
```